# reverse engineer excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel vba formula that I am trying to reverse the formula , the Sub letterToHex works great. But I cant work out how to get the final stages of working it in reverse , to get the Hex code converted back to CPJ. I have managed to get the first few stages working in Sub HextoLetter

```
Sub LetterToHex()

R1 = "CPJ"

N1 = Asc(Right(R1, 1)) - 64 ' Result is ASCII value of letter J is  (74) - 64  = 10

N1 = N1 + (Asc(Mid(R1, 2, 1)) - 64) * 64 ' Result is ASCII value of letter P is (80) - 64 * 64 = 1234 + N1 value 10 = 1034

n11 = (Asc(Left(R1, 1)) - 64) * 64 ' Result is ASCII value of letter C (67) - 64 =3 * 64 = 192

N1 = N1 + n11 * 64 ' result is 13322

N1 = N1 + 14680064 ' Result is 14693386

N2 = Hex(N1) 'Result is N2 = E0340A
dec = CLng("&H" & N2)

notfound:

End Sub

Sub HextoLetter()
hexcode = "E0340A"
dec = CLng("&H" & hexcode) '14693386
shortdec = dec - 14680064 '13322

End Sub
```

I need to get the HextoLetter code completed to get the hexcode E0340A converted back to CPJ

additional code showing for

```
Sub LetterToHex_CPK()

R1 = "CPK"

N1 = Asc(Right(R1, 1)) - 64 ' Result is ASCII value of letter K is  (75) - 64  = 11
MsgBox N1
N1 = N1 + (Asc(Mid(R1, 2, 1)) - 64) * 64 ' Result is ASCII value of letter P is (80) - 64 * 64 = 1234 + N1 value 11 = 1035
MsgBox N1
n11 = (Asc(Left(R1, 1)) - 64) * 64 ' Result is ASCII value of letter C (67) - 64 =3 * 64 = 192
MsgBox n11
N1 = N1 + n11 * 64 ' result is 13323
MsgBox N1
N1 = N1 + 14680064 ' Result is 14693387
MsgBox N1
N2 = Hex(N1) 'Result is N2 = E0340B
MsgBox N2
dec = CLng("&H" & N2)

notfound:

End Sub
```

Comment: (What's "CPJ"?)

Comment: Please fix the comments in your code! `N1 = Asc(Right(R1, 1)) - 64 ' Result is 10 for (C)` because `Right(R1, 1)` is `J` **not** `C` as in the comment. Check all comments and fix them. This is very confusing, and probably the issue why you cannot get it work yourself! • I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. • And change your variable names `R1`, `N1` and `n11` etc to something meaningful so your code is readable.

Comment: Thanks . Yes I have changed them. I know that ASCII Character value for J is 74. So N1 = Asc(Right(R1, 1)) - 64 ' Result is 10 for (J)  is correct.

Comment: ++ Amazing question! Had to literally scratch my head to get the solution :D

Answer (score 2):

You have a sum in your first procedure

```
N1 = N1 + n11 * 64
```

therefore the formula cannot be reverted!

#### Explanation:

Imagine you have the sum `5 + 4 = 10`. Then you cannot revert it if you only know the sum `10` and you want to know `a + b = 10` then there is more than one solution for `a` and `b` (actually there are infinite solutions for that).

Therefore the answer is: Your Hex code cannot be reverted into the 3 letters.

Comment: The formulas remain the same , the only data that changes is the 3 letter code CPK  code has been added

Comment: @JDB You didn't understand my answer. If you have the Hex code `E0340A` there is *no formula* to get it back to `CPJ`. That is mathematics you just cannot do that. What you are trying to achieve is impossible.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: `Your Hex code cannot be reverted into the 3 letters.` I could be wrong but I think it is possible? :P

Comment: @SiddharthRout Okay, a brute force attack is not a formula. That's cheating ;) That's not what I call *reverting* a formula. What you do is calculating the hex over and over with all letter combinations until you find *one* possible combination that produces the same hex that you want to "revert". Btw did anyone proof that all 3 letter combinations produce a unique hex? • Nevertheless you got my vote for a workaround that works for that specific case.

Comment: That specific case? ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry, I meant the case of having 3 letters only, which in first place makes a brute force possible (in a acceptable amount of time), while with more letters a brute force will easily blow up your time to calculate all combinations. But still nice workaround to brute force while a mathematical solution is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

> N1 + n11 * 64

The above can be written as

```
 N1 = N1 + (n11 * 64)
```

which is the same as

```
 N1 + ((Asc(Left(R1, 1)) - 64) * 64)
```

which is the same as

```
 (N1 + (Asc(Mid(R1, 2, 1)) - 64) * 64) + ((Asc(Left(R1, 1)) - 64) * 64)
```

which is the same as

```
 (Asc(Right(R1, 1)) - 64 + (Asc(Mid(R1, 2, 1)) - 64) * 64) + ((Asc(Left(R1, 1)) - 64) * 64)
```

Building on this logic it is **possible** to get what you want

Here is a function for it

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shortdec As Long, dec As Long
    Dim hexcode As String

    hexcode = "E0340A" 
    'hexcode = "E0340B" '<~~ This will give you CPK

    dec = CLng("&H" & hexcode) '14693386
    shortdec = dec - 14680064 '1332

    Debug.Print GetString(shortdec)
End Sub

 Function GetString(n As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
    Dim x As Long

    For i = 65 To 90
        For j = 65 To 90
            For k = 65 To 90
                a = Asc(Chr(i)) - 64
                b = (Asc(Chr(j)) - 64) * 64
                c = (Asc(Chr(k)) - 64) * 64

                x = (a + b) + c * 64
                If x = n Then
                    GetString = Chr(k) & Chr(j) & Chr(i)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
 End Function
```

My assumptions: You will use Capital letters. Else you will have to loop through ASC 97 to 122 as well.

Comment: I have also been struggling to find a way to get a formula working to get the hexcodes based on the same 3 digits . examples are LBM = E49124  / NPC = E48D79 / MRV = E4849F . Is there a way to loop through formulas to find the correct formula.

Comment: As per your original code, the hex of LBM is `E0C08D` and not `E49124`

Comment: yes the formula will be different as this is from another country. each country has a different formula

Comment: The you will have to customize it accordingly. I would recommend going through the code and understanding how it works...

Comment: This is the formula for another country type 
    hexcode = "7C4908"
    shortdec = dec - 8126464 ' different value
  
'formula is different
    For i = 65 To 90
        For j = 65 To 90
            For k = 65 To 90
                a = Asc(Chr(i)) - 65
                b = (Asc(Chr(j)) - 65) * 36
                c = (Asc(Chr(k)) - 65) * 36

                x = (a + b) + c * 36  result is OPM

Comment: I already helped you once. Now you need to show some effort yourself. Also in one post, you can ask only one question ;)